# Object not showing up in render (not a set visibility issue)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have a weird problem with some of my objects: they don't show up in the render.
I'm using blender 2.92 with a brand new portable pc which has an rtx 2060 and I'm using cycles and optix.
Here's a list of things I've checked and weren't the issue:

- Setting render visibility
- Looking for correct facing normals
- Looking if I had instancing set to none
- Looking if I set the shader wrong
- Looking if I had keyframes issues
- Looking for modifiers/parenting/constraint issues
- Looking for collection issues
- Looking for Layers issues

And it looks right in the viewport. Please tell me if I missed something!

Here's some screenshots:
[image: Scene Setup]
[image: Viewport Render (intended result)]
[image: Compositing Setup + Final Render + Layers Setup]

Comment: can you provide blend file?

Comment: I can't find a way to do it, unfortunatly...

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then follow instructions

Comment: I've been trying to get it to work for half an hour now and it just keeps telling me that there is an internal issue. I'm going to try to tell GiantCowFilms, but it doesn't seem to work for the moment.

Comment: I'd concentrate on one object, by removing everything else, then checking if it still doesn't display in the render, if indeed the settings of it are to render (with many objects it's easy to get confused and look at settings of a wrong object), I'd try to render also in Eevee to make sure it's not some engine dependent setting, I would create a new material for the object. And if that doesn't work, sharing a single object is more likely to work.

Comment: It's the subdivision surface. For some reason, when it's set to adaptive, it disapears. Why though?

Comment: and it dosn't do it on every objects